# Not getting proper Values from child Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have a parent component Test.js that gets a list of questions along with its options similar to this

```
[{"id":18,"question":"which command removes untracked filed from working directory","options":["git clean"," git pull"," git copy"," git branch"]},{"id":19,"question":"how many layers of Git are present","options":["1"," 5"," 6"," 4"]},{"id":17,"question":"git fetch + git merge = ?","options":["push","pull","copy"," clone"]}]
```

my Parent Componet

```
    const Test = (props) => {
  
    const location = useLocation();
  const { linkId } = location.state
    const [currentQuestionIndex, setCurrentQuestionIndex] = useState(0);
    const [markedAnswers, setMarkedAnswers] = useState([]);
    const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
      axios
        .get(`http://www.example.com`)
        .then((response) => {
          setQuestions(response.data);
          setMarkedAnswers(new Array(response.data.length));
          setIsLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }, [linkId]);
  
    const submitAssessment = () => {
      console.log(markedAnswers);        // Logic to submit the assessment
      };

      const setAnswer = (index) => {
        setMarkedAnswers((arr) => {
          const newArr = [...arr];
          newArr[currentQuestionIndex] = index;
          return newArr;
        });
        setCurrentQuestionIndex(currentQuestionIndex + 1);
      };
  
    return (
      <div className="quiz-screen">
      
        {isLoading ? (
        // <div className="loading">Loading...</div>
        <div
        className="spinner-container"
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Spinner animation="border" role="status" style={{ color: "#10ccf4" }}>
          <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </Spinner>
      </div>
      ) :questions.length > 0 && currentQuestionIndex < questions.length ? (
          <Question
            question={questions[currentQuestionIndex]}
            totalQuestions={questions.length}
            currentQuestion={currentQuestionIndex + 1}
            setAnswer={setAnswer}
            linkId={linkId}
          />
        ) : (
          <div className="assessment-completed">
          <h2>Assessment Completed</h2>
          <button onClick={submitAssessment}>Submit</button>
        </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

i have a child component Question.js where iam sending the questions and other few parameters

```
function Question({ question, totalQuestions, currentQuestion, setAnswer }) {
      const webRef = useRef(null);
      const [url, setUrl] = useState(null);
      const [screenshotCount, setScreenshotCount] = useState(0);
      const [showEndScreen, setShowEndScreen] = useState(false);
      const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
      const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(null);
      const [selectedAnswer, setSelectedAnswer] = useState(null)
    
      const onUserMedia = (e) => {
        console.log(e);
      };
      
      const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null);
      const timer = useRef(null);
      const progressBar = useRef(null);
    
      async function gotoNextQuestion() {
        if (timer.current) {
          clearTimeout(timer.current);
        }
        if (selectedAnswer) {
          flushSync(() => {
            setAnswer(selectedAnswer);
          });
        }
        setSelectedOption(null);
        setSelectedAnswer(null);
      
      }
    
      useEffect(() => {
        progressBar.current.classList.remove("active");
        setTimeout(() => {
          progressBar.current.classList.add("active");
        }, 0);
        timer.current = setTimeout(() => {
          gotoNextQuestion();
          setUrl(null);
        }, 10 * 1000);
        return gotoNextQuestion;
      }, [question]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
          setTime((t) => t + 7);
        }, 3000);
        setIntervalId(intervalId);
        return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
      }, [screenshotCount]);
    
      const webcamRef = React.useRef(null);
    
      const handleImageCapture = async () => {
        const imageSrc = webcamRef.current.getScreenshot();
        try {
          const formData = new FormData();
          let data = {
            id: 1, //dataRef.current.id,
          };
          data = JSON.stringify(data);
          formData.append("data", data);
          formData.append("image", dataURLtoFile(imageSrc, "photo.png"));
          const res = await axios.post(
            `http://localhost:5000/`,
            formData,
            {
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
              },
            }
          );
          console.log(res.data);
          if (res.data.result == false) {
            setScreenshotCount((x) => x + 1);
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
          //TODO: show error in ui or something
        }
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (screenshotCount < 5) {
          handleImageCapture();
        } else {
          clearInterval(intervalId);
          setShowEndScreen(true);
        }
      }, [time]);
    
      if (showEndScreen) {
        return <div>End Screen</div>;
      }
    
      return (
        <div>
          <Card
            style={{
              width: "15rem",
              height: "10rem",
              justifySelf: "center",
              marginLeft: "12rem",
              marginTop: "1rem",
            }}
          >
            <Webcam
              ref={webcamRef}
              screenshotFormat="image/png"
              onUserMedia={onUserMedia}
            />
          </Card>
    
          <div className="question" style={{ marginTop: "2rem" }}>
            <div className="progress-bar" ref={progressBar}></div>
            <div className="question-count">
              <b>{currentQuestion}</b> of <b>{totalQuestions}</b>
            </div>
            <div className="main">
              <div className="title">
                <span>Question:</span>
                <p>{question.question}</p>
              </div>
              <div className="options">
                {question.options.map((option, index) => {
                  return (
                    <div
                      className={
                        index === selectedOption ? "option active" : "option"
                      }
                      key={index}
                      onClick={() => {
                        setSelectedOption(index);
                        setSelectedAnswer({answer:option, qid:question.id})
                        setUrl(null);
                      }}
                    >
                      {option}
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="control">
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  gotoNextQuestion();
                  setUrl(null);
                }}
              >
                Next
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export const dataURLtoFile = (dataurl, filename) => {
      const arr = dataurl.split(",");
      const mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1];
      const bstr = atob(arr[1]);
      let n = bstr.length;
      const u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
      while (n--) {
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
      }
      return new File([u8arr], filename, { type: mime });
    };
    
    export default Question;
```

When i do console.log() of markedAnswers iam getting something like

```
[
    {
        "answer": " git pull",
        "qid": 18
    },
    {
        "answer": " git pull",
        "qid": 18
    },
    {
        "answer": " 4",
        "qid": 19
    }
]
```

which is not what i want as you can see the question is getting repeated in the markedAnswers

Comment: need more info, like GitHub repository, to take a closely look of what is happening